# Можно ли рассчитать относительную ширину элемента от родителя без учета отступов?

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox, width, padding

Есть обертка с шириной 1200px, в ней список. Списку обнуляю отступы по умолчанию и задаю падинги по бокам 6%. Элементам списка задаю ширину 20%, в итоге по факту ширина элементов получается 211px, вместо 240px. То есть считает 20 процентов от 1200px-6%*2. Можно ли как то это решить?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 6%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  min-height: 40px;
  list-style: none;
}


/* ширина элементов должна быть 240px(20% от 1200, а получается 211px) */

.item {
  width: 20%;
  outline: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item">Информация</li>
        <li class="item">Фото </li>
        <li class="item">Карта</li>
        <li class="item">Гостиницы</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем случае flexbox сжимает пропорционально ваши .item

Comment: Тоже сначала так подумал, но flexbox не сжимает ничего, можно попробовать задать flex-shrink: 0.
Ничего не изменится

Answer (score 1):

Задайте `padding` обертке, например:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
.nav{
 padding: 0 6%;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  min-height: 40px;
  list-style: none;
}


/* ширина элементов должна быть 240px(20% от 1200, а получается 211px) */

.item {
  width: 20%;
  outline: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item">Информация</li>
        <li class="item">Фото </li>
        <li class="item">Карта</li>
        <li class="item">Гостиницы</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, тогда содержимое вылезет. Как вариант маргины 6% задать по краям первому и последнему элементам. Надо будет проверить на соответствие макету

Answer (score 0):

Эта проблема решается добавлением одного свойства:

```
.menu {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Не забывайте про устройство box model :)

Comment: Хм, возможно я ошибаюсь, ибо новичок в этом деле. Но ведь тогда размер родителя станет больше обертки в 1200px и она вылезет. А если уменьшить .menu, то результат от моего отличаться не будет

Comment: Wrapper 1200, поэтому никто не увеличиться, и блоки останутся 211px

Comment: так 211px это не 20% :) нужно 240px

Пока нашел такое решение: результат можно добиться добавив первому элементу и последнему по краям родителя margin 6%

Comment: @Руслан да, про общую длину я упустил момент. На вашем я бы просто сделал `.item { width: calc(1200px * 0.2); }`

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko тогда ширина элементов становится фиксированной(можно сразу 240px писать), а не относительной

Answer (score 0):

```
100 / (100-6*2) * 20 = 22.72727272727273
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 6%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  min-height: 40px;
  list-style: none;
}


.item {
  width: 22.72727272727273%; /* теперь 240 */
  outline: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item">Информация</li>
        <li class="item">Фото </li>
        <li class="item">Карта</li>
        <li class="item">Гостиницы</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```